# Finding a cover of an open set in the Euclidean space with some refined conditions.

Tags: general-topology

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Is it possible to find a countable collection of open balls whose clousres are contained in $U$ and the union of these open balls equal $U$?

I am concerned with the condition that the closures must be contained in $U$... Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider all balls with rational midpoint and radius that are $\subseteq U$. Now halve their radii.

Comment: Oh thanks!! This certainly gives the desired cover!